# Component not working in angular and also doesn't show any error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components

Unable to render html file using component. It doesn't show any error and also controller inside component is not been called.

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('graphApp', []).component('graphDetail', {
    templateUrl: './graphDetail.html',
    controller: function() {
      console.log('I am in component');
    },
    bindings: {
      options: '='
    }
  });
})(window.angular);
```

Comment: Where are you using this component? Please include all the relevant details.

Comment: <graph-detail options='ctrl.options'></graph-detail>

Comment: I'm not sure why is this causing an issue, because your code looks correct to me. Check your browser's console for any errors.

Comment: It's not showing any error

Comment: might be silly, but are you sure your js with this code is included?

Comment: Another silly thing to check is whether you didn't forget to put the ng-app in your html

Comment: i solved it by setting up the server and run it on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in this DEMO:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('graphApp', []).component('graphDetail', {
    template: `<fieldset>graph-detail</fieldset>`,
    controller: function() {
      console.log('I am in component');
    },
    bindings: {
      options: '='
    }
  });
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="graphApp">
  <graph-detail options></graph-detail>
</div>
```